# How to enumerate over an nsmutablearray of CGPoints?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray, cgpoint

Here is the code I have:

```
for (NSValue * i in cgpointarray){
        [text setHidden:NO];
        CGPoint temppoint = i.CGPointValue;
         if (touchended.x < temppoint.x+36 && touchended.x > temppoint.x-36 && touchended.y < temppoint.y+36 && touchended.y > temppoint.y -36){
             spacetouched = i;
             break;
        }
```

The purpose is to search each space (cgpoint x of array) +or- 36 pixels for the touchended CGPoint. However I have created a label named text and set it to hidden, when this code runs the text label does not show up, therefore I think that it is not executing the code. The cgpointarray is an NSMutableArray if that makes any difference.

edit: on this line: `CGPoint temppoint = i.CGPointValue;` the compiler says: local declaration of 'i' hides instance variable

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint or a log statement in the loop to tell for certain whether the loop is simply not executing or if something else is wrong? Because there are a number of possible reasons for what you're describing.

Comment: Put a log statement inside the loop `NSLog(@"text is %@",text)`, then you'll know if this loop runs, how many times, and if 'text' is nil. Also, `[i CGPointValue]` would probably be the preferred syntax here (opinion)

Comment: @FirozeLafeer I put an NSLog in the loop, nothing happens, when it is before the loop i se an output. also changed to '[i CGPointValue]'

Comment: OK, then check to see that cgpointarray isn't nil. And if it is not nil, check to see that it isn't empty `[cgpointarray count]`. Then with that information in hand, you can work your way back from there.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer I inserted [cgpointarray count] and it says null, however it SHOULD be populated with 16 CGPoints, i used this code to insert the cgpoints: [cgpointarray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(board.center.x + 109, board.center.y + 109)]];

Comment: Did you check that `cgpointarray` is not nil?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you fix the warning - seems like you have an instance variable also called i ?

Comment: I do not know how. or what it means.